# C# multiline string with html

Tags: c#, string, syntax

Is it possible to have a multiline C# string that contains html?

The following works fine:

```
        string output = @"Qiuck 
                        brown
                        fox
                        jumps
                        over
                        the
                        lazy 
                        log";
```

But this does not work:

```
            string output = @"<object>
                        <node>
                        <param value=\"test\" />
                        </node>
                        </object>
                        ";
```

However this similar example does work, I have just taken out the attribute on param:

```
            string output = @"<object>
                        <node>
                        <param />
                        </node>
                        </object>
                        ";
```

Any suggestions on the best way to package html into a string variable?  If it is not possible I am assuming the next best method is just to read from a file? Any other ideas?

The problem with example 2 seems to be the escaped quotes.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use double quotes instead of escaping them.

```
    string output = @"<object>
                    <node>
                    <param value=""test"" />
                    </node>
                    </object>
                    ";
```

Comment: Nitpick: technically, it is still escaping, only with a different escape character :)

Answer (score 9):

Use `""` instead of `\"`. It will still output `"`. When you're doing literal strings, the escape character isn't processed:

```
string output = @"<object>
                      <node>
                          <param value=""test"" />
                      </node>
                  </object>
                  ";
```

Comment: To make the meaning less ambiguous: When you're doing _verbatim_ literal strings, the _normal string_ escape character isn't processed.

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes in the param.